# Edit text position despite the text length

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make something like a course list with a button to enroll that course .
I was trying to make this button stay in it position and make the text whenever it get closer to the button goes to a new line (not under the picture but under Certificat .... )

[image: Screenshot]

```css
.paddtext{
padding-left:10%;
}

.inline{
display: inline;

}

.preview {
    height: 120px;
    width: 170px;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

.coursprev{
    margin-top: 2%;
    border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #1b1b1a;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
 
}

.joincourse{
    margin-left: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="coursprev">
<img class ="preview" src="../../../media/img/python.png" alt="PreviewVideo"> 
<h6 class="nomCertif paddtext inline">Certificat : [FETCH NOM CERTIF] 
 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</h6>   
<a class="button-highlight joincourse" href="#">Commencer!</a> 
</div><br>

<div class="coursprev">
<img class ="preview" src="../../../media/img/python.png" alt="PreviewVideo"> 
<h6 class="nomCertif paddtext inline">Certificat : [FETCH NOM CERTIF] 
</h6>   
<a class="button-highlight joincourse" href="#">Commencer!</a> 
</div><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, You can divide your components and use `flex` and then you can use `flex-wrap` if you want to or text will be get wrap automatically

Secondly, you need to keep some space between the long text so it can be a break and wrap as no word will be longer than 20 chars

I have created [JSbin](https://jsbin.com/buyevaputo/edit?html,output) with your example and done the modification

```css
.paddtext{
  padding-left:10%;
}

.inline{
  display: inline;

}

.preview {
  height: 120px;
  width: 170px;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.coursprev{
  margin-top: 2%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #1b1b1a;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
 
}

.joincourse{
    margin-left: 15%;
}


.display-flex{
  display: flex
}

.flex-1{
  flex: 1
}

.flex-2{
  flex: 2
}

.align-items-center{
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="coursprev display-flex">
  <div class="flex-1">
   <img class ="preview" src="../../../media/img/python.png" alt="PreviewVideo"> 
  </div>
  <div class="flex-2">
    <h6 class="nomCertif paddtext inline">Certificat : [FETCH NOM CERTIF] WWWWWWWWWW WWWWW WWW  WWWWW WWWWWWW  WWWWWW WWW WWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWW WWW  WWWWW WWWWWWW  WWWWWW WWW WWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWW WWW  WWWWW WWWWWWW  WWWWWW WWW WWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWW WWW  WWWWW WWWWWWW  WWWWWW WWW WWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWW WWW  WWWWW WWWWWWW  WWWWWW WWW WWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWW WWW  WWWWW WWWWWWW  WWWWWW WWW WWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW</h6>   
 </div>
  <div class="flex-1 display-flex align-items-center">
    <a class="button-highlight joincourse" href="#">Commencer!</a> 
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="coursprev display-flex">
  <div class="flex-1">
   <img class ="preview" src="../../../media/img/python.png" alt="PreviewVideo"> 
  </div>
  <div class="flex-2">
    <h6 class="nomCertif paddtext inline">Certificat : [FETCH NOM CERTIF] </h6>   
 </div>
  <div class="flex-1 display-flex align-items-center">
    <a class="button-highlight joincourse" href="#">Commencer!</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the button should always be aligned right of the content then just add below class to your `Commencer` button -

```
.fix-commencer {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 51px;
}
```

> The `margin-right can be adjusted as per your requirement`

Full code -

```css
.paddtext{
padding-left:10%;
}

.inline{
display: inline;

}

.fix-commencer {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 51px;
}

.preview {
    height: 120px;
    width: 170px;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

.coursprev{
    margin-top: 2%;
    border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #1b1b1a;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
 
}

.joincourse{
    margin-left: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="coursprev">
<img class ="preview" src="../../../media/img/python.png" alt="PreviewVideo"> 
<h6 class="nomCertif paddtext inline">Certificat : [FETCH NOM CERTIF] 
 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</h6>   
<a class="button-highlight joincourse fix-commencer" href="#">Commencer!</a> 
</div><br>

<div class="coursprev">
<img class ="preview" src="../../../media/img/python.png" alt="PreviewVideo"> 
<h6 class="nomCertif paddtext inline">Certificat : [FETCH NOM CERTIF] 
</h6>   
<a class="button-highlight joincourse fix-commencer" href="#">Commencer!</a> 
</div><br>
```

Comment: Yes that's what I want for the button . I guess for the text to be aligned in the new line I need to use overflow right ?

Comment: @JuniorDev, What do you mean by align in new line?

Answer (score 0):

Just describe your `.coursprev` class with `diplay: flex;`, `justify-content: space-between;`, `align-items: center;`:

```
.coursprev {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 25px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #1b1b1a;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

then do specific adjustments for your situation.